# Normalize the following scenario

Tags: normalization

A college keeps details about a student and the various modules that the student has studied. These details compromise Registration number, Name, Address, Tutor Number, Tutor Name, Diploma Code, Diploma Name and repeating fields for module code and module name and result. Normalize the relation.

Comment: You should try to do your own homework...

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few resource, like [this](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/) and [this](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) - once you understand it, it'd simple... think in terms of sets of data and you won't go far wrong

Hint - most tables are obvious (answers in the question), you will also need a table that links two of them together

Comment: Good answer: Lead them but don't feed them when it come to stuff that smells strongly of homework.